# Deriviative of natural log help finding

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

$$y=7\ln\frac{11}x$$

I need to use the product rule please

$$\frac{d}{dx} (7) \cdot(\ln(11/x) + \frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln\frac{11}x\right) \cdot 7$$

then

$$0+\frac{d}{dx}\frac{11}x \cdot7$$

what do i do

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \ln \frac{11}x = \frac{d}{dx}(\ln 11 - \ln x) = 0 - \frac1x.
$$
The derivative of the first term is $0$ since $\ln 11$ is a constant.

You can also use the chain rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln\frac{11}x = \frac{1}{11/x}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\frac{11}x
$$
and then you have to find that last derivative.  When you're done simplifying you'll get the same answer.  But this method is more complicate than what is necessary, since you can use the first method above.

You don't really need the full-fledged product rule since $7$ is a constant, so you can say
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(7\ln\frac{11}x\right) = 7\frac{d}{dx}\ln\frac{11}x. 
$$

Comment: ? still having trouble

Comment: @Daniel : Try being more specific.  What part are you still having trouble with?

Comment: The part where i have the eliminated the left part of the equation multiplying by 0. What do i do with the right side. i have 7 * d/dx[(ln(11/x). how dow i use the chain rule

Comment: You need to recall that $\dfrac{d}{du} \ln u=\dfrac1u$.  That gets you $\dfrac{1}{11/x}$.  But then the chain rule says you need to multiply that by $\dfrac{d}{dx}\,\dfrac{11}{x}$.  Since $11$ is a constant, this is $11\dfrac{d}{dx}\,\dfrac{1}{x}$.  Do you know how to find that last derivative?